# Why do the chargers produce persistent high pitch sound?

Tags: electricity, acoustics

I have noticed that my Nexus Orb charger and a charger for the shaver produce some unpleasant high pitch sounds - near the fork.

Why are they doing this? Does it indicate any problem with my chargers, or is it simply an overall technological issue?

Comment: That sounds like a problem with your chargers to me. The frequency they emit should be well above the limit of human hearing. Don't take that as meaning you might have super-human hearing, the range they emit at should be impossible to hear. Something you should ask on the manufacturers' sites

Comment: It probably is not a problem with the chargers. What is happening is that something is in resonance with the charging frequency and is vibrating. The pitch is high since the charging frequency has been changed from 60 Hz to about 40 kHz. The vibration may be at 1/2 of this frequency.

Comment: @Jim I hardly believe that I have collected two unrelated chargers with similar problems. But either way - I'm curious about the explanation of why this sound appears.

Comment: As noted by LDC3 the 40kHz frequency is the probable culprit. What you hear is likely to be a subharmonic of this frequency. In old TV's sometimes a similar situation occurred.